# Oracle CATSEARCH not handling special characters

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

I've create an Oracle Text index like the following:

```
create index my_idx on my_table (text) indextype is 
    ctxsys.ctxcat parameters('index set my_table_iset');
```

Now when I run my query:

```
DECLARE
  cnt  NUMBER;
  attr VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
  attr := 'BECKMANNS';
  SELECT COUNT(text)
  INTO cnt
  FROM my_table
  WHERE catsearch(text, attr, '') > 0 ;
  dbms_output.put_line( '->' || cnt);
END;
```

This works. But when I change the value of

```
attr := '"BECKMANNS"'
```

I get a error:

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50943: query token too long on line 1 on column 1
```

I found in the Oracle documentation that I can wrap the special characters in brackets

```
attr := '{' || '"BECKMANNS"' || '}'
```

but this still gives the same error. I tried variations of this, to no avail.

any ideas?

Comment: maybe try this: attr := q'{"BECKMANNS"}';